# mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-5.5

I deployed a web app built with Laravel on Amazon's ElasticBeanStalk, after setup, I tried accessing the page but I got HTTP 408 error. I setup the loadbalancer to listen on port 80 and 443, and also there is a certificate attached to port 443.

I accessed the log for and found this `mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled`, I have tried searching for solutions but I am yet to get anything similar.

Any help will do. Thanks

Comment: have you tried to re-init the instance? make sure you have configured SSL on [as describe here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html)

Comment: I terminated the instance, started afresh but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as enabling `mod_ssl` goes, you'll have to download the module and load it as it doesn't come preinstalled on Amazon Linux. I add `mod24_ssl` in a config file under .ebextensions:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl: []
```

This should install `mod_ssl.so` under `/etc/httpd/modules/`, and IIRC there should be an existing file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf` that will run `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`

Not sure if `mod_ssl` is the root cause of your issue, but this will load `mod_ssl` at least. I actually had different issues with HTTP 408s before (not from production traffic, but apparently from unused connections the load balancer keeps open) and it resolved itself by updating the Apache server based on advice from here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=307846